# JS - Dynamically change Textfield

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, input

I'm trying to change the value in one textfield from the value of another textfield without any submits. Example:

[Textfield 1 (type 'hello')]

[Textfield 2 ('hello' is inserted here as well)]

Below is my form:

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
   <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="">
   <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
```

I don't know much about JavaScript, is this even possible? Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why has this been given a negative rating? Please comment here on whats wrong with my question, and I'll do my best to improve it. There's no point in giving negative rating and not bothering to leave feedback... It helps no one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
   <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onKeyUp="document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value">
   <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
```

see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/4PAKE/

Comment: This works well, but it only changes the value after I click off the field. Is it possible to change the value in textfield 2 in real time? Thanks

Comment: connect it to `onKeyUp` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="field" value="" onChange="changeField()">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeField() {
    document.getElementById("field").value="whatever you want here";
}
```

**Sometimes this won't work.** So you need to use [micha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859877/micha)'s solution:

```
<form action="#" id="form_field">
   <input type="text" id="textfield1" value="" onChange="document.getElementById('textfield2').value=this.value">
   <input type="text" id="textfield2" value="">
</form>
```

See this solution in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PAKE/)

You can read more about `.value` [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with jquery, then please add the following script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

and then write the following code:

```
$("#textfield1").bind("input", function() {
    $("#textfield2").val($("#textfield1").text());
}
```

Comment: Might want to note to the OP that you're solution requires jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to accomplish this as @sarwar026 mentioned but there are some problems with his answer. You can do it with jQuery with this code:

```
$('#textfield1').blur(function() { 
    $("#textfield2").val($("#textfield1").val());
}​);​
```

In order to use jQuery you'll need to include it on your page, before your script.