# Dynamically change value of form in JS

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b52h0ws7/2/)** is an example jsFiddle. I have two fields.. opp3 and opp4. The user can modify the text in opp4 but I want the text in opp3 to dynamically change when a user changes the text in opp4.

I saw **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177487/js-dynamically-change-textfield)** solution to dynamically change text but I cannot use that exactly because I am creating a greasemonkey script (and cannot edit the html, only add JS) and i want to only change a portion of the field, not the whole thing.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="opp3" maxlength="120" name="opp3" size="40" tabindex="1" type="text" style="cursor: auto; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" readonly>

<br><br>

<input autocomplete="off" id="opp4" maxlength="255" name="opp4" onchange="getElementByIdCS('opp4_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('opp4_mod').value='1';" size="40" tabindex="2" type="text">
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById('opp3').value = "Text <VALUE FROM OPP4> More Text";
document.getElementById('opp4').value = "Field Text Here";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an event listener on the opp4 input to achieve this.

```js
var opp3 = document.getElementById('opp3')
opp3.value = "Text <VALUE FROM OPP4> More Text";
var opp4 = document.getElementById('opp4')
opp4.value = "Field Text Here";

opp4.addEventListener('input', function () {
    opp3.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="opp3" maxlength="120" name="opp3" size="40" tabindex="1" type="text" style="cursor: auto; background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" readonly>
    
   <br><br>
       
       <input autocomplete="off" id="opp4" maxlength="255" name="opp4" size="40" tabindex="2" type="text">
```

Comment: Perfect! I modified the opp3.value so it concatenates the text I wanted with this.value.

Answer (score 0):

You may accomplish a *similar* result minus an event listener, as follows:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var opp4 =   document.getElementById('opp4');
opp4.value = "Field Text Here";

var opp3 = document.getElementById('opp3');
opp3.value = "Text <VALUE FROM OPP4> More Text";  
inputs[1].onchange = function(){ 
          opp3.value = opp4.value;
          };
```

See demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYbWea)

Admittedly, with an eventlistener it's a bit cooler since the changes occur simultaneously. I like that effect but what about users? Will they find it fun or a disconcerting distraction? My solution exhibits the same dynamic behavior that the person who posed the question liked at http://jsfiddle.net/4PAKE/

Comment: The problem is that `onchange` only fires on blur. You will not see changes in the two inputs simultaneously.